# TornadoFX map ObservableList to different ObservableList

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have an `ObservableList` containing a number of custom objects (`val rolls: ObservableList<Roll>`). Each of these objects has a `val results: ObservableList<Pair<Int, Double>>`. The Pairs represent a possible number and the chance for this result occurring. I would like to visualize these pairs in a `BarChart`. The `Roll`s also contain the name for the series. The results, names and the list of rolls can change at a later time (through user input) and that should be reflected in the chart.

A minimal sample of the class `Roll` looks like this:

```
class Roll (
    val results: ObservableList<Pair<Int, Double>>,
    initialName: String
){
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(initialName)
    var name by nameProperty
}
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
barchart(x = CategoryAxis(), y = NumberAxis()) {
    data = rolls.map { roll ->
        XYChart.Series<String, Number>(roll.name, roll.results.map { (result, chance) ->
            XYChart.Data<String, Number>(result.toString(), chance)
        }.asObservable())
    }.asObservable()
}
```

This successfully maps the data to the correct form and displays it. The problem with this approach is of course that it does not reflect changes to `rolls` or elements in `rolls`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is putting a change listener on the list that updates the chart and puts change listeners on all relevant properties of the `Roll`s (which also update the chart):

```
barchart(x = CategoryAxis(), y = NumberAxis()) {
    animated = true
    updateData(this)
    rolls.forEach {
        it.nameProperty.onChange { updateData(this) }
        it.results.onChange { updateData(this) }
    }
    rolls.onChange {
        updateData(this)
        it.addedSubList.forEach {
            it.nameProperty.onChange { updateData(this) }
            it.results.onChange { updateData(this) }
        }
    }
}
```

To that end I put the data conversion function I mentioned in my question into a separate function:

```
fun updateData(chart: BarChart<String, Number>){
    chart.data = rolls.map { roll ->
        XYChart.Series<String, Number>(roll.name, roll.results.map { (result, chance) ->
            XYChart.Data<String, Number>(result.toString(), chance)
        }.asObservable())
    }.asObservable()
}
```

The solution still feels somewhat dirty though, so if anyone knows a cleaner way to do that I would appreciate it.